# Using separate JS file in JSP not working

Tags: javascript

I have a JSP and i am trying to use JavaScript and putting my JS code in a separate JS file and adding the url reference to it in my JSP, below is code snippet

JSP

```js
my JS file(script.js)

function showPopupWindow() {
            document.getElementById('popupWindow').style.display = 'block';

        }
```

```html
`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url src="/resources/script/script.js"/>"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="divpopup" style="display:none;"> Poping up!!</div>

<div><a onclick="showPopupWindow()">create</a></div>


</body>
</html>

`
```

The issue here is when I use a separate JS file, it is not working for me.I see no result after clicking the create button.

Comment: `popupWindow` !== `divpopup`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

function showPopupWindow() {
            document.getElementById('popupWindow').style.display = 'block';

```
    }
```

The issue with my code was that I mistakenly used different element name for my div in my JS function,  It should refer to "divpopup" not "popupWindow". Now it is working.